I have a problem with dsbulk loader and a data connection with Cassandra
Can someone help me? I need to enter a .csv file into a table I created in Cassandra. I have looked for problems in the syntax of my dsbulk loader but I cannot find what the error could be.
The code of cassandra table is
CREATE TABLE aire (
estacion text,
titulo text,
latitud text,
longitud text,
fecha text,
periodo text,
so2 text,
no text,
no2 text,
co text,
pm10 text,
o3 text,
dd text,
vv text,
tmp text,
hr text,
prb text,
rs text,
ll text,
ben text,
tol text, 
mxil text, 
pm25 text, 
primary key (estacion, fecha, periodo));

And the code in CMD Console for dsbulk is
dsbulk load -url ~/Downloads/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-censususually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB/Data8277.csv -k newzealand -t census --schema.mapping "Year = year, Age = age, Ethnic=ethnic ,Area=area ,Sex = sex, count=count"

The error is
Operation LOAD_20240509-223924-806000 failed unexpectedly: Com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.connectors.api.Connector: Provider com.datastax.oss.dsbulk.connectors.csv.CSVConnector could not be instantiated.
   Caused by: Com/univocity/parsers/common/Format.
     Caused by: Com.univocity.parsers.common.Format.

Have you had any similar errors? How can it be solved?
The solution, please. I need this now, please.

I hope you're running with DSBulk version 1.11.0, if not, please upgrade to that. You could check the version by running ./dsbulk --version command.
Next, you need to specify the mapping properly. For example, you've "Year = year in your command line. There is no such column in your table called year.
For example, if your input CSV consist of below sample records,
header1,header2
1,2

and if your table schema goes like,
create table if not exists demo (col1 primary key, col2);

in order to load that, we could provide a mapping like header1=col1,header2=col2 (if we were to match all headers with table columns).
Please refer to the documentation here at https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/reference/schema-options.html#schemaMapping for more details on how to set up mapping.

I was getting the same error as you described.
I solved it by using the dsbulk jar file.
Solution:
java -jar dsbulk-1.10.0.jar load -url ~/Downloads/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-censususually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB/Data8277.csv -k newzealand -t census --schema.mapping "Year = year, Age = age, Ethnic=ethnic ,Area=area ,Sex = sex, count=count"
